# How do you Change the Folder Template for Computer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do you change the folder template in Windows Explorer for the top 'Computer' folder in Windows Vista?  To change the template for most other folders, I'd right-click in the folder view and select the Customize This Folder option from the context menu, but when I right-click on Computer, the context menu doesn't show a 'Customize this folder' option.

The alternative - right-clicking then selecting Properties also does not work on the Computer Window, since if I do that on the Computer folder, I just get the System Properties dialog instead of the Explorer folder options properties dialog that any other folder gives me.

I want to change the template because the Computer template on my machine has been corrupted into one that, even in Details view, shows only one column, the drive names. I want to get back to viewing all columns, most specifically including the amount of free space on each partition.

Answer (score 1):

By 'template', I'm assuming the folder options.  (and that you're in Win XP)

The way I've always done it is:

1. Open a single file in windows explorer (doesn't matter which one).
2. Set all the options you like (i.e.- details view, specific columns, et al)
3. In the Folder Options window, on the View tab
4. the top section asks if you want to apply the view to all folders
5. click that and whenever you open up any new folders, it should have the same view.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I mean. The template is different from the folder options - it's the thing that says whether this folder is to be treated eg. as containing music, pictures, documents or 'all items'. Depending which template is available changes - as I understand it - what columns are available to display in details view. You normally access it by right-clicking on a folder, selecting Customize this Folder from the context menu, and then on the dialog that comes up selecting from the 'Use this folder type as a template' drop-down list.